# What IsNull() means in the where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

| product_id | product_name | product_description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fans | Panasonic fans |
| 2 | Refrigerator | Toshiba refrigerator |
| 3 | Light | Edison bulb |
| 4 | Laptop | NULL |

The product table is shown as above.

```
select * 
from product 
where isnull(product_description, null) = product_description
```

The SQL script is what I am trying to run.

Can I know how to read or what does it actually mean for the conditions? Why the row 4 is not selected? Feel like the query is same as

```
select * 
from product 
where product_description is not null
```

I am a little bit confused about the conditions in the query.

Comment: `ISNULL(product_description, NULL) = product_description` makes no sense, if product_description is `NULL` it pointlessly replaces it with `NULL` and then it does an `=` condition that will only be `true` for `not null` product_description. So it is just an unnecessarily obfuscated way of writing `where product_description is not null` as you suspect

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call when trying to understand a T-SQL function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) takes in two arguments. It returns the first one unless it's null, in which case it returns the second argument - so writing something like `ISNULL(SomethingHere, NULL)` is meaningless - which means the where clause is the same as `where product_description = product_description`.

Since in T-SQL `NULL = NULL` returns `UNKNOWN` (which is equivalent to `false` in the context of a `WHERE` clause), it's basically the same as `where product_description is not null`.